# Gaussian Distribution generation for an array

Tags: c, random

I am trying to apply method 2 described here: [Gaussian Distribution](http://c-faq.com/lib/gaussian.html).
The problem is I have an array of 4 numbers with range from 0-1 and I want to generate a gaussian distribution for that range. I have coded this but it isn't correct. Where I am going wrong ?

```
float a[3]={0.3,0.7,0.2,0.1};
for (int k=0; k<3; k++) {
  for (int k1=1; k<4; k++) { 
    if(phase == 0) { 
      U = (rand() + a[k]) / (RAND_MAX + a[k1]);
      V = rand() / (RAND_MAX + a[k]);
      Z = sqrt(-2 * log(U)) * sin(2 * pi * V);
    } else Z = sqrt(-2 * log(U)) * cos(2 * pi * V);
    phase = 1 - phase;
    printf("\n%f",z);
  }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you getting an error or are the results different than you expected?  If the latter, in what way?

Comment: thank for the comment

Yes The result is different even, It some times gave me negative values

is this ok ?

Because when I test it with Matlab then the values are not negative

Comment: First problem: The "a" array has 4 elements but is only declared to have three.
Second problem: the inner for loop mentions k for the comparison and increment operations. This is probably an error.

Comment: Thanks for the correction I have fixed the both , not It's giving me same output values after 2 values example:
0.34
0.54
0.34
0.54
0.34
0.54
I have used the Srand function refresh the random values everytime

Comment: srand() should be invoked once to initialize the random number generator, often times done with the return value of time(NULL). Then use rand() from then on out. This could be why you get the same pairs of numbers over and over.